# Locate two buttons one inside the other

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm trying to put two buttons one inside the other with html. I have tried this:

```
<div id="photoShow" style="width: 190px; height: 212px">   
   <input type="button" runat="server" id="btn_ShowImage" style =" background-image: url('photos/Analog50.jpg'); width: 55px; height: 54px;"  
           onclick="return btn_ShowImage_onclick()" /><asp:Button 
        ID="btn_AddProductToReservation" Height="180px" Width="194px"   
        runat="server" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;" /> 
  </div>
```

Would love to get some help, Thank you

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Buttons cannot contain other buttons. You could make on of the buttons a `div` and add the click handler to it...

Comment: You can't nest buttons. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @BalintBako Buttons can contain other elements, just not all of them. No other buttons, links, inputs etc..

Comment: Thx @MrLister, that is correct. I've changed my prev comment accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

put them in a div like that:

```
<div style="float:left"><button></button><button></button></div>
```

so you can put them aside eachother, there is no sense putting buttons in each other!

Answer (score 0):

if you use twitter bootstrap you can put those buttons one inside another:

```
<div class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
    out out 
  <div class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
    in in
    </div>
    out out 
  <div class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
    in in
    </div>
    out out 
</div>
```

and it will render as expected